# Is it possible to find out init vector if we know encrypted data and the key

Tags: c++, openssl

Using a key and init vector I have encrypted some data:

```
QString & msgToEncrypt = "some message";
QString & key = "01234567891234560123456789123456";

EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ctx;
unsigned char iv[16];
int len, ciphertext_len;
unsigned char ciphertext[msgToEncrypt.size() + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, (const unsigned char *) key.toStdString().c_str(), iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, (const unsigned char *) msgToEncrypt.toStdString().c_str(), msgToEncrypt.toStdString().size());
ciphertext_len = len;
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len);
ciphertext_len += len;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Then I get the encrypted data.

I wonder if it is possible to find out what was the iv using encrypted data and the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a block cipher and Ciper Block Chaining (e.g. `aes_128_cbc`), without a way to determine if the resulting plaintext is correct or not, no.

If you look at the encryption, the first block XOR's the plaintext and the IV, and then encrypts that. To decrypt you just do the opposite, you decrypt the blocks cipher text, then XOR it with the IV. Following blocks use the previous ciphertext instead of the IV (the "chaining"), so for decryption only the first block needs the IV.

So, if you have the key you can decrypt the first block, but then what do you use for the XOR? Without a way to determine if the encrypted plaintext is correct or not, the IV could be anything.

But given any knowledge about the plaintext at all, determining the IV then becomes fairly easy as each bit of the IV directly maps to the corresponding output bits in predictable ways. For example say 128 bit AES encrypts a message starting with `GET /questions/5`, then you could get the IV just by XORing the decrypted block with that plaintext. And because the following blocks use the previous ciphertext, not the IV for the XOR, you can get those directly anyway.

[image]